# Adding timestamp infront of jpeg data to sending it over a websocket

Tags: c

I am sending jpeg's to websocket clients with [wsserver](https://github.com/Theldus/wsServer), now I want to add a unix timestamp infront of jpeg data so that the binary message looks like this:

```
<timestamp><jpeg_data>
```

then I can slice that on js side to compute a latency.

```
static void send_frame(gpointer addr, gpointer client, gpointer provider)
{
    ImgProvider_t* p = provider;
    Watcher* c = client;
    // p->buffer_data is the jpeg pointer
    // p->timestamp are the timestamp as unsigned long long
    ws_sendframe_bin(c->connection, p->buffer_data, vdo_frame_get_size(p->frame));
}
```

Thats my first programm with c so I have a lack of knowledge. I come from pyton where I would convert the timestamp to bytes and concate them togehter.
But here in c, I dont know how to convert the unsigned long long to bytes and append that infront of the p->buffer_data pointer.

Thank u If u have any tipps for me =)

Comment: What exactly is your problem? How to get the timestamp? How to send it? You seem to know how to send data (which I assume that `ws_sendframe_bin` does), so could you not do the same for the timestamp?

Comment: I want to send the timestamp and the jpeg together in one ws_sendframe_bin call.

Comment: Unless you create a new buffer, copy both the timestamp and the frame data into that buffer, you can't. Why do you want to use only one call? Assuming you use a TCP connected socket, it can coalesce multiple send-calls into a single packet (assuming the data to send can fit in a single packet).

Comment: One call of ws_sendframe_bin is one message on js side, I want to drop the image if the latency to high. I will try to create a new buffer and copy ts and jpeg data into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to send the timestamp and the jpeg together in one ws_sendframe_bin call.

I don't think there's any free lunch here if you can't split the data into two separate websocket messages.  You're going to have to allocate a new buffer to serialize both the timestamp and image bytes into.

In the adjustment to your code below, I'm assuming only one thread calls send_frame. I'm also assuming sizeof(p->timestamp) is a fixed type (like `uint32_t`) that isn't variable in size between architectures since the receive side can be running anything as well.

```
static void send_frame(gpointer addr, gpointer client, gpointer provider)
{
    static uint8_t* tmp = NULL;
    static size_t tmpsize = 0;

    ImgProvider_t* p = provider;
    Watcher* c = client;

    size_t needed = vdo_frame_get_size(p->frame) + sizeof(p->timestamp);
    if (needed > tmpsize)
    {
        free(tmp);
        tmp = malloc(needed*2); // double needed so we don't keep repeating this operation
        tmpsize=needed*2;
    }

   
    memcpy(tmp, &p->timestamp, sizeof(p->timestamp));  // include <string.h> for memcpy
    memcpy(tmp+sizeof(p->timestamp), p->buffer_data, needed-sizeof(p->timestamp));


    ws_sendframe_bin(c->connection, tmp, needed));
}
```

The above is just a suggested and easy hack to accomplish what you want. You are not obligated to have the `tmp` buffer be a static variable inlined into the function. You could allocate and/or define it elsewhere.

Comment: Your code will leak memory if memory have already been allocated once.

Comment: works as I want great !!!!!!!

Comment: @Christoph - don't forget to add the `free` statement before the `malloc` like I updated above.

Comment: @selbie you are a good man bro =) thank u